# Why should winter tires not be used at summer?

Tags: tires

I heard a tire salesman say winter tires are dangerous in summer.

What are the structural and material features that make winter tires not suitable for summer use?

Answer (score 8):

Due to materials used and design, they tend to overheat and fail.  Winter tires are also typically not speed-rated like Summer tires (since they can't handle the heat of higher speeds).

Comment: Heat is a huge issue, especially if we are talking about studded winter tires.